# How do you add a cell array to a plot title in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, cell-array

I have created a loop in MATLAB to automate some FFT work. The loop selects a new .mat files each time through. I have extracted a cell array which references the test data being processed (for example *Test 1*), and I would like to use that information in the title of the figures I produce.

I have tried

```
title(fileInfo);
```

Here, `fileInfo` contains *Test 1*.

What do I need to do to be able to get this information into the figure on each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, how you are calling your matfiles, but this is the good method to achieve the task:

```
matfiles = dir('*.mat') ;

for i = 1:length(matfiles)
    %% do waht you want
    figure
    title(matfiles(i).name)
end
```

Straight away to your question. You can get title like below:

```
fileInfo = 'Test 1';
figure
%% plot
title(fileInfo)
```

Or straight away:

```
  figure
  % plot
  title('Test 1')
```

Comment: Thank you! the `title(matfiles(i).name` did the job!